# What makes an abstract physical system describable by a "fluid" equations of motion?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism

We can describe (some of) the dynamics of many systems using fluid mechanics. Of course these include classical fluids like water, more exotic fluids like photon gases and the universe as a whole and even solid(ish) things over long times, like glasses and ice. Further still we can treat general classical systems in phase space using a phase fluid, quantum systems (e.g. Madelung equations) and with a little bit of hand waving anything that happens on a symplectic manifold (which gives us a Hamiltonian and hence a flow and Louiville's theorem).

So what is it about a system that makes it obey a fluid model? Are there systems that definitely do not fit a fluid model?

(I realise that I haven't said exactly what I mean by "fluid model", this is somewhat deliberate. If you like you can take it to mean "having equations of motion which are (almost) identical in some form to the Euler equations".)

**edit:**
Since admittedly, the original question wasn't quite clear I'll try to clarify a bit. I'm not looking for a high-school answer, or one which describes only actual literal physical fluids, e.g. "a fluid doesn't support a shear stress", "a fluid is something you can wash your hair with". I've given some examples above of situations that fit this description, and without further explanation I think it's non-obvious what a "mean free path" or similar would mean in a generalised fluid. What I'm really looking for (and there may not be any) is some overarching physical or mathematical principle, or failing that an argument as to why there isn't one. I'd even be quite happy to be directed to a book or more appropriate forum. I apologise for not being clearer before and appreciate the answers already given.

Comment: A fluid is nothing more than a material that "flows" (deforms continuously under shear stress).  I think what you are really trying to ask is under what circumstances can a material be modeled as continuum.  There are many systems that lend themselves to continuum approximation.  Some of those systems deform continuously under shear stress and are therefore analogous to fluids.  Regardless, the equations of motion remain the same, but the equation of state of a fluid will always be independent of deformation history.

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) would clarify/simplify/stress what is really being asked.

Comment: @Qmechanic I've amended the question and hopefully the aim is somewhat clearer now

Comment: @SeanD Your question is now even more confusing. *So what is it about a system obey a fluid model?*  The answer is quite simple and I know you don't find it enlightening, but it really is as simple as if it "doesn't support shear stress."  There is no other magical quality that makes a system a "fluid."

Comment: @SimpleLikeAnEgg except that the concept of "shear stress" isn't (obviously) meaningful in many of the above-mentioned situations. Or are you saying there should be some generalised notion of this for each system?

Comment: @SeanD Yes, there is a generalized notion of shear stress for each of those systems which is independent of deformation history and that is part of why you can approximate them as fluid continuum.  If you want to understand shear stress on a molecular level you should look into the kinetic theory of gases.  In that case shear stress is the result of momentum transport from molecular diffusion.  I can imagine other sources of shear stress for other systems, but as long as it is independent of deformation history then the system is a fluid.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic definition of a fluid is

> a fluid is a substance that continually [deforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_%28mechanics%29) (flows) under an applied [shear stress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_stress).

To model a fluid using the [Euler equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_%28fluid_dynamics%29), you need to satisfy the condition that the [mean free path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path) of a particle, $\ell$, is significantly *smaller* than the typical size of the domain, $L$ (and also that [viscosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) and [heat conduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_conduction) are negligible/zero). The ratio of $\ell/L$ gives one the [Knudsen number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knudsen_number).

You can calculate the mean free path via
$$
\ell=\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\pi\sigma^2}
$$
where $n$ is the number density and $\sigma$ the mean particle size. For a hydrogen gas cloud ([astrophysical context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_cloud) here), we expect $n\sim10\rm cm^{-3}$ with $\sigma\sim10^{-8}\,\rm cm$ (diameter of hydrogen atom) which gives
$$
\ell\sim10^{14}\,\rm cm
$$
There are a few common scale lengths in astrophysics, two relevant ones are (a) the [AU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit) ($10^{13}$ cm) and (b) the [parsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsec) ($3\cdot10^{18}$ cm). Clearly (a) is less than the scale length so the fluid equations won't work for modeling it on this scale, whereas (b) the fluid approach would work (and is used).

As far as the more exotic situations, I presume that the fluid description is an approximation, but I'm not sure of the justifications for doing it (outside the Knudsen relation).

Comment: Your answer is partial and indirect.  For a start, that is not a valid definition for a fluid.  A fluid is simply something that deforms continuously under shear stress.  What you have given is an explanation as to when a material might be treated as a continuum.  The author is indirectly asking about this as well, but you should correct your definition for a fluid.

Comment: @SimpleLikeAnEgg: You are correct. I have amended my post to reflect this fact.

Comment: Not sure why you had a negative 1... anyways, +1 because you mentioned the same thing that came to mind as soon as I read the question (your quote). @SimpleLikeAnEgg - another definition for a fluid that I like is - *a fluid is any substance that takes the shape of the container it occupies* (when acted under gravity).

Comment: @KyleKanos nice answer, but what does it even mean to have a mean free path for something that isn't ultimately particulate?

Comment: @IsopycnalOscillation that definition only applies to a very narrow class of real fluids, for example the hydrogen cloud above hardly fits

Comment: @SeanD: I'm not sure what you mean "something that isn't ultimately particulate." Surely every fluid is made up of *some* particles, no?

Comment: Also, the hydrogen cloud *certainly* can be modeled as a fluid at the parsec scale. And it is [done so regularly](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=triggered+star+formation+hydrodynamics) (link to Google Scholar search for *triggered star formation hydrodynamics*)

Comment: @KyleKanos is a phase fluid made of particles? What about about a quantum probability fluid? And while nobody will disagree the hydrogen cloud behaves as a fluid at large scales, I would disagree that it " takes the shape of the container it occupies".

Comment: @SeanD: Phase fluids (AFAIK) apply Hamilton's e.o.m. to an idealized set of particles, so definitely particles. As to the QPF, I'm not versed enough in it to say any sort of justification for it. I never said a fluid is something that takes the shape of its container, I said that it is something *that deforms continuously under an applied shear stress*. No one can argue that it's not.

Comment: @SeanD Can you expand on why a hydrogen cloud would not fill the shape of a container? I see no objection for a fluid, which is what a hydrogen cloud is, to metamorphose into any shape commandeered by an eager force, since, after all, it cannot resist shear...

Comment: @IsopycnalOscillation well you'll agree that it's not currently in a container. If you were to put a large, comoving box around it it wouldn't change shape to reflect that. All the same if you squeezed it into a toothpaste tube it would certainly take that shape. It is undeniably a fluid, but describing that in terms of container shapes wouldn't be the approach I'd take. 
All the same I think that this question really hasn't gone where I wanted it to and I'm happy enough to let the discussion die.

Comment: @SeanD OK, sometimes the answer is simpler than we anticipate. Don't get too hung up on it.

Comment: For the record I don't feel like any of the answers addressed the question as I meant it (rather than wrote it). I'm  a grad student who's done plenty of fluid mechanics (particularly in astrophysical contexts) and while the current answers are helpful to somebody else, they're nothing I couldn't read in a textbook. I was hoping the `mathematical-physics` tag would help here but nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

I think expecting "fluid" behaviour in terms of a material that does not support shear, is not useful in the context of the various systems you have listed in the question. Instead, I believe you are intuitively connecting ideas and concepts pertaining to conservation laws. So the idea that in specific systems, conserved charges (in the sense of Noether) have associated conserved currents or fluxes that cause it to "flow" within the system, respecting a continuity equation, is possibly when one uses the correspondence to fluids (in which, one typically has mass and momentum conservation, and possibly energy). This is about the extent of the connect to fluids, as the flow is in all likelihood not occurring in real space.

The other important thing to keep in mind is that continuum fluid dynamics is a phenomenological classical field theory (in the sense that it uses field variables instead of discrete objects to describe the system). This means that it applies only as a coarse-grained model at large length scales and long time scales. Hence, before using a fluid like or any field description of a system, it is imperative to understand the regime and separation of scales in the macroscopic problem.