# What can be an example or a scenario where the continuum definition of fluid mechanics would not be valid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics, approximations

The continuum definition of fluid mechanics may not be valid if a system contains too few molecules cause properties such as density, concentration and velocity are not well defined at a mathematical "point". 
I can't think of an actual scenario or case when this may happen. What are some examples where this definition breaks down?

Comment: [Free molecular flows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_molecular_flow) such as [partial vaccuums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum), [rarefied gas flows](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Rarefied+gas+flow), [membrane permeation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_gas_separation#Nanoporous_Membranes), etc. When you scale things down to where the length scale of the system are on the order of the mean free path of molecules then the continuum *approximation* (quantified by the [Knudsen number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knudsen_number)) starts to break down.

Comment: This post (v4) seems like a list question.

Comment: Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102132/25301

Comment: Google "Knudsen Effect"