# Transition between continuum mechanics and molecular physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, continuum-mechanics

Is it known what is the critical value for the number of particles (atoms, molecules) below which the system can not be described as a continuous media [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Continuum_mechanics)?

Comment: It would depend entirely on the physics that you're interested in modelling. In the case of mechanical stress, for instance, [this paper](http://pubs.rsc.org/-/content/articlelanding/2014/cp/c3cp54357a/unauth#!divAbstract) places the threshold at approximately 5 nm.

Comment: @lemon It depends on the physics. How about fluids?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102132/25301